Android Build System Unable to Find "bison" Executable Despite Correct Path
Description:
I am trying to build the Android source code, but I'm encountering an issue with the build system failing to locate the bison executable, even though the executable exists at the specified path.
Steps to Reproduce:

Run the make command to build the Android source code.
The build fails with the following error:

/bin/bash: prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison: No such file or directory
make: *** [build/core/binary.mk:633: /home/eeleeleel079/los/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/checkpolicy_intermediates/policy_parse.cpp] Error 127

Environment:

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Google Cloud)
Android Source Version: Lineage OS 13.0 for SM-J320FN

Question:
Despite taking the above steps, the build system is still unable to locate the bison executable. Can anyone provide guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
Additional Information:

The bison executable is present at the path prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison.
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Checked the file permissions and made the bison executable executable.
Updated the BISON_PATH variable in the build/core/binary.mk file to point to the correct path.
Cleaned the build and rebuilt the checkpolicy component.
Inspected the build logs for additional clues or error messages.
Verified that the directory containing the bison executable is included in the PATH environment variable.



